# SSL on JBOSS AS 7

Tags: java, ssl, jboss

I installed JBOSS AS 7 and I need to configure it to work with https connections. My Authority can sign only pkcs format requests, so I need to generate a request in that format (I assume with openssl). On jboss documentation there are steps only for keytool (which does not generate in my desired format) so I need step by step guideline for pkcs. I'm a beginner in this area so, if someone could help me with steps on how to generate and configure my jboss for https, I would be so thankful. I know google exists, but I couldn't find anywhere all the steps for configuration and for the csr part I find so many options to do it and I don't know which one is the one that will work for me.  I know I'll have to change some things in standalone.xml, but I don't know exactly what....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did this by converting my key and my certificate (with it's chain), which were in PKCS format into a jks keystore (my key and my certificate chain).